# Limit of a composition of functions

Tags: real-analysis, limits

If $\lim_{x\to \infty} \{f(x)-g(x)\} = 0$, and $F(x)$ is defined on reals such that  for all reals $b<\frac{dF}{dx}<a$, then prove or disprove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(F(f(x))-F(g(x)\right) = 0$.

I am not quite sure if this is true. Please provide counter examples and its quite possible I ignored some really obvious ones.

Here's how far I've progressed.

Let's say for some $\varepsilon_1$ we have  $0<|h|<\delta_1 \implies \left|\frac{F(f(x)+h)-F(f(x))}{h} - F'(f(x))\right|<\varepsilon_1$ and we choose $h$ such that $f(x)-g(x)=h$ (which must be possible since the limit of that function exists and tends to zero), then I get, 
$|F(g(x))-F(f(x))|<min(|ha+\varepsilon_1|,|hb-\varepsilon_1|)$. Is it now possible to show that the RHS of the inequality can take all possible values for suitable $h$ and $\varepsilon_1$ and if so how?

If the above theorem can hold only for suitable conditions on $a$ and $b$, find them. I'd also like to know, if the above is disproved then when if $\lim_{x\to \infty} \{f(x)-g(x)\} = 0$ does 
$\lim_{x\to\infty}\left(F(f(x))-F(g(x)\right) = 0$.

The last two parts of the problem have not been worked out to any extent by me so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the mean value theorem. We have that for each $x$ there is some $\xi_x$ between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that 
$$ (F \circ f)(x) - (F\circ g)(x) = F'(\xi_x) \cdot \bigl(f(x) - g(x)\bigr) $$
Now taking abosulute values and using the condition on $F'$, we have 
$$ \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\abs{(F \circ f)(x) - (F \circ g)(x)} \le \max\{\abs a, \abs b\} \cdot \abs{f(x) - g(x)} $$
Now let $x \to \infty$.

---

Addendum: The statement of the mean value theorem is as follows:

> **Mean value theorem**. *Suppose $h \colon [c,d] \to \mathbf R$ is continuous and differentiable on $(c,d)$. Then there is some $\xi \in (c,d)$ such that 
>   $$ h(d) - h(c) = h'(\xi)(d - c). $$*

We apply it here for the function $h := F$ for each $x$ on the intervall $[c,d]$ with $c := \min\{f(x), g(x)\}$ and $g := \max\{f(x), g(x)\}$, that gives us an $\xi_x$ (the subscript reminds us on the $x$-dependence), such that 
$$ F\bigl(f(x)\bigr) - F\bigl(g(x)\bigr) = F'(\xi_x)\cdot \bigl(f(x)-g(x)\bigr) $$
and now the boundedness of $F'$ can be used.

---

The mean value theorem is very useful in cases where we want to bound terms in $F$ using properties of $F'$, so if you didn't encouter it up to now, it's a useful theorem.

---

In your approach, note that the $\delta_1$ you get, does not only depend on $\epsilon_1$, but also on $x$, and I do not see a way to work around, we must in some way garuantee that for all large enough $x$ we have $|f(x)-g(x)| \le \delta_{1}(x)$ and I do not see how this can be acchieved.

Without any condition of $F'$, the conclusion does not hold, think of $f(x) = \sqrt x$, $g(x) = \sqrt{x+ 1}$, and $F(x) = x^2$, then 
\begin{align*}
  g(x) - f(x) &= \sqrt{ x+1} - \sqrt{x}\\
              &= \frac{x+1 - x}{\sqrt{x+1} + \sqrt x}\\
              &= \frac 1{\sqrt{x} + \sqrt{x+1}}\\
              &\to 0,\quad x \to \infty\\[5mm]
\text{but  } F(g(x))  - F(f(x)) &= x+1 - x\\
                                &= 1\not\to 0
\end{align*}

Comment: So you're saying it holds? I am not familiar with the mean value theorem, or real analysis in fact, (I barely started a week ago, and I had the idea of this problem while trying to solve a limit in trigonometric functions) so I would appreciate if you could elaborate on that.

Comment: It holds, yes ... ${}{}{}$.

Comment: Is there a way to approach the problem as I had mentioned in the post? Using the inequality I obtained at the end?

Comment: @Johann Some problem with that is that $\delta$ may depend both on $\epsilon$ and on $x$

Comment: Yes. That is precisely the problem I was having. I was hoping that there might be some way to eliminate that.

Comment: @martini Thanks a lot for the clarification :)

Comment: @Johann Added something.

Comment: @martini did notice that. I observed the counter example for $e^x$. The idea that such a theorem may exist came from a similar problem  $\lim_{x\to\infty} \cos(\sqrt{x+1})-\cos(\sqrt{x})=0$.

Comment: @martini The above theorem seems to hold for all $c$ (being limit points of the domains) when $x\to c$ when $R_f \subset D_F$ and $R_g \subset D_F$ as well. I suppose that's correct?

Comment: So simple answer for a seemingly complicated problem. +1